# Symfony2 router - how to call annotation route

Tags: symfony, routes

Simple case. In my all app I'm using Route annotation driver, defined in `routing.yml` as follows:

```
MyBundle:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /someprefix
```

Some action in MyBundle's Ctrl controller looks like:

```
@Route("/{page}/{status}", name="default_action", defaults={"page" = 1, "status" = "ok"}, requirements={"page" = "\d+"})
public function defaultAction($page, $status) {...}
```

Now I want to make this action - default action when visiting my web page. I cannot use just `@Route("/")` because I'm prefixed. So I'm adding to `routing.yml`:

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Ctrl:default }
```

And there is where problem starts - Symfony2 is calling default controllers action not from annotation but just from action and I get error:

`Controller "...:defaultAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$page" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).`

So simply Symfony2 is not obtaining default values from @Route annotation.

Question is: how to call route for `_welcome` that is aware of @Route?

Answer (score 0):

You've missed defaults in yml settings, should look like this:

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Ctrl:default, page: 1, status: ok }
```

Comment: But I want to miss it - it's already declared in @Route! So why I should do it twice? :/

Comment: Because you're re-declaring it in yml; they're completely different settings that don't know anything about each other.